# Trigonometric identity between sines of multiples of $\pi/70$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that:

$$\left(\sin\frac {9\pi}{70}+ \sin\frac {29\pi}{70} - \sin\frac {31\pi}{70}\right) \left(\sin\frac {\pi}{70}-\sin\frac {11\pi}{70} - \sin\frac {19\pi}{70}\right) =\frac {\sqrt {5} -4}{4}$$

I Could not get any idea to solve. Please help

Comment: @Andrei, I know that's the solution. But I did not get that. Its too long and confusing...

Comment: It is a consequence of the (cosine addition)=(sine product) formulas and a particular [Gauss sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum).

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio, I did not understand. What do you want to say?

Answer (score 0):

use the following identity
$$\sin x={\frac {e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}}$$

Comment: I could not get that. Could you please elaborate a bit more.?